# CGAL Reading and Writing OBJ Texture

Tags: cgal

Hoping someone could please provide a snippet to read and write OBJ files with CGAL including normals and UV.

The only way I can think of is to write a reader and writer.

Is there a simple way to extend or re-use the existing reader and writer?

Appreciate any guidance.

Bare minimum example. `mesh-in.obj` contains `vt` records, `mesh-out.obj` does not.

```
Mesh mesh;
CGAL::IO::read_polygon_mesh("mesh-in.obj", mesh);
CGAL::IO::write_polygon_mesh("mesh-out.obj", mesh);
```

Should I parse the `vt` records from the input OBJ file and append as named parameters?

Comment: The reader for OBJ is basic and does not read UV maps. You can use the following function to read OBJ and other formats: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLIOFct.html#ga49f5b5e6fbfcbfaaac7604c88e10915c

Comment: Thanks for the advice @sloriot, I am still unclear as to how best associate the `vt` records with the vertices.

Comment: Except if you modify the CGAL code, it won't be possible with an OBJ.

Comment: I see, I don't actually need to use the UV coordinates, I just want to persist them through some clip operations. I'll see if I can parse and add them as a property map or something.